# How to debug net::err_failed/415 Unsupported Media Type error on POST request?

Tags: javascript, ajax, http

We have an API (made by a backend dev from our team) which I'm trying to use in a Vue app. Previously I've successfully made some `GET` requests to APIs via [`axios` HTTP client](https://github.com/axios/axios), so I expect no problems because of the framework itself. I'm trying the following:

```
const data = JSON.stringify(someObject);
axios.post(process.env.VUE_APP_DEV_API_ENDPOINT + `/examination/conclusion`, data)
```

which returns gets 415 Unsupported Media Type response. Ok, request headers contain

```
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

while swagger shows for that `POST` API

[image: possible content types: application/json, application/json-patch+json, application/*+json, text/json]

Makes sense, I've tried to change the request to

```
axios.post(process.env.VUE_APP_DEV_API_ENDPOINT + `/examination/conclusion`, data, {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json-patch+json',
    },
})
```

but that brings me "(failed)" in (Vivaldi) dev tools on the place of HTTP request code and "(failed) net::ERR_FAILED".. ok, Chrome dev tools show that axios actually sends `OPTIONS` request instead of `POST`! Why is that? (Vivaldi console says that it is `POST` request which fails, though). The request is cross-domain (from localhost to a remote server) and this one (unlike the request sent without headers settings) also causes this error in console:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at '[my API path]/examination/conclusion' from origin 'http://localhost:8081' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

If this is a CORS issue, why I got 415 without those headers and no CORS complaint? Is it? **How can I fix this?** Why axios sends an `OPTIONS` request instead of `POST`? Or it doesn't and that's a quirk of Chrome dev tools? This is so inconsistent, not sure where to continue..

I've found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47762097/3995261) but that one recieved no answers..

PSs

1. ok, in FireFox the second request is also shown to send an `OPTIONS` request which then gets 404 response and console shows [CORSPreflightDidNotSucceed](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSPreflightDidNotSucceed) and [CORSDidNotSucceed](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSDidNotSucceed) errors. I've asked our backend dev and they suppose CORS is enabled for the whole app so it seems this is more likely a problem of axios.
2. a couple of axios issues that may be related: [2345](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/2345), [2083](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/2083)
3. hm, looks like axios doesn't have to do anything about this.

   ```
   fetch(process.env.VUE_APP_DEV_API_ENDPOINT + `/examination/conclusion`, {
       method: 'POST',
       body: data
   })
   ```

   gives the same 415 response,

   ```
   fetch(process.env.VUE_APP_DEV_API_ENDPOINT + `/examination/conclusion`, {
       method: 'POST',
       headers: {
           'Accept': 'application/json',
           'Content-Type': 'application/json'
       },
       body: data
   })
   ```

   gives the same `(failed) net::ERR_FAILED` result
4. looks like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37668444/3995261) answers most of the "why?" questions, but not "how to fix?" one
5. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12320736/3995261) looks to be more related to the "how to fix?" aspect (I've shown it to our backend dev, we'll see if it helps)